# How to make choses in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, image, text, random

I have a problem here.

```
function random_imglink() {
    var myimages = new Array() //specify random images below.You can have as many as you wish
    myimages[1] = "http://i.imgur.com/abaIWZt.jpg"
    myimages[2] = "http://i.imgur.com/POVb0m7.jpg"

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length) if (ry == 0) ry = 1
    document.write('<img src="' + myimages[ry] + '" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
```

So, this script will show a random picture. but i want to make like a text, so if it shows the first picture i would like to make some text saying "Image 1" and if it shows the other picture i would like it to say "Image 2" a underline text of the picture of course, but i dont know how to do it. i really want to help here.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function random_imglink() {
    var myimages = ["http://i.imgur.com/abaIWZt.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/POVb0m7.jpg"];

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length);
    if (ry == 0) ry = 1
    document.write('<img src="' + myimages[ry] + '" style="border: none;" alt="" />');
    document.write('<span style="font-style: italic;">');
    switch(ry) {
        case 1:
          document.write('Image 1');
          break;
        case 2:
          document.write('Image 2');
          break;
        default:
          break;
    }
    document.write('</span>');
}
random_imglink();
```